# JMeter Correlation - New Line

Tags: jmeter, correlation

Please let know how to do correlation from below given code for FaxNumer whose value is "ctl02". This value "ctl02" will change depending on number of details added. The script is performing task of adding first an fax number to an account and then update it. So whenever we have to update a fax details it will be dependent on "test12345" from first line. "test12345" will be parametrized and its value will change everytime.

I have tried various option but not able to correlate it properly.

Kindly let me know in case more information is required.

Comment: <td align="left" name="test12345" style="font-size:Small;"> </td><td> 
                    <input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvFax$ctl02$imgbtnEdit"

Comment: What post processor are you using? Please show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), both can work with parent/child associations and siblings.

If you aren't very familiar with CSS or XPath locators and need assistance in developing appropriate expression update your question with some more lines of HTML code around.